# linuxkit auditd example?

Tags: docker

[auditd(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditd.8.html) is required to run at host (not in container) as discussed like the followings:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/auditd-inside-a-docker-container/134739
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/53311314/921859

However, I found that a container image at [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxkit/auditd) and [linuxkit github repository](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/tree/master/pkg/auditd).  I tried to run the image but I could not because 1) the CPU architecture is different (`docker run` complained that 'no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries') and 2) I tried to run `yum install audit` in the centos:7 container in my PC and run `auditd -f` but it failed as 'Cannot change priority (Operation not permitted)'.

Is there any example to run auditd in container, is it required some --privileged, or is it just data aggregation as [this](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2018-July/msg00078.html) says ?